# kotlinx-coroutines-test. withContext {...} in liveData {...} doesn't switch back to the previous context after its finish

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing an integration test for my Android app. And I've faced an issue with `liveData {...}` coroutine builder: when I call `withContext {...}` function inside of it, it switches to a given context (e.g. `Dispatchers.IO`), but does not switch back after return (to `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`).

The test looks like:

**WordFragmentIntegrationTest:**

```kotlin
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(application = TestAppWithDaggerComponent::class)
class WordFragmentIntegrationTest {

    @get:Rule
    val coroutinesRule = CoroutinesRule()

    private val mockWebServer = MockWebServer()

    @After
    fun teardown() {
        mockWebServer.shutdown()
    }

    @Test
    fun `should fetch a word from api and populate the view`() = runBlockingTest {
        // Mock api response, it works fine.
        val response = MockResponse().setResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                                     .setBody(SAMPLE_API_WORD_JSON)
                                     .setBodyDelay(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        mockWebServer.enqueue(response)
        mockWebServer.start(8080)

        // Launch a Fragment under test. It triggers an api call.
        val fragmentScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<WordFragment>()

        // Wait for the Fragment to do its work.
        fragmentScenario.onFragment { fragmentUnderTest ->
            runBlocking {
                while (fragmentUnderTest.isLoading) { yield() }
                
                // Do some assertions...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CoroutinesRule:**

```kotlin
class CoroutinesRule : ExternalResource() {

    override fun before() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(TestCoroutineDispatcher())
    }

    override fun after() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

---

And a piece of code, which causes test failure.

**WordViewModel:**

```kotlin
val wordLiveData = liveData {
    printCurrentThread("Emitting the first value")
    emit(UIState.ShowLoading)

    val value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        printCurrentThread("Fetching a value")
        loadWordUseCase(wordId)
    }

    printCurrentThread("Emitting the second value")
    emit(value)
}

private fun printCurrentThread(message: String) {
    val threadInfo = "Thread: ${Thread.currentThread().id}. UI thread: ${Looper.getMainLooper().thread.id}"
    println("$message. $threadInfo")
}
```

It works fine in production environment:

```bash
Emitting the first value. Thread: 1. UI thread: 1  # First emitting is on the UI thread.
Fetching a value. Thread: 365. UI thread: 1        # Fetching is on some IO thread.
Emitting the second value. Thread: 1. UI thread: 1 # Switched back to the UI thread.
```

But in the test environment (where `Dispatchers.Main` is replaced) `withContext {...}` does not switch back to `liveData {...}`'s `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`, and it causes `CoroutineLiveData` crash, because its `emit()` should be called from the UI thread.

```bash
Emitting the first value. Thread: 11. UI thread: 11  # Emitted on the UI thread.
Fetching a value. Thread: 19. UI thread: 11          # Switched to IO thread.
Emitting the second value. Thread: 19. UI thread: 11 # Didn't switch back, which caused:

Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#2"
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:462)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:304)
...
```

---

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? E.g. maybe I have a wrong `CoroutinesRule`?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `TestCoroutineDispatcher` does not switch back to a specific thread  like android's `Dispatchers.Main` does. Instead it behaves similar to `Dispatchers.Unconfined`.

I am not sure whether this will work with Robolectric, but what worked in unit tests was this:

Add the `InstantTaskExecutorRule` to your test like you did with your `CoroutinesRule`. e.g. :

```
@get:Rule
val executorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

This will allow calling `LiveData.setValue(...)` on any thread.

Since `emit` eventually just delegates to `setValue`, there is no need to adjust your ViewModel code

If the rule is not already available, add this dependency:

```
testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
```

If that still doesnt help, I would like to know what happens if you do not replace the Main dispatcher